# Z3 solver installed but I can't import anything

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, z3

I've installed z3-solver package from PyPi in my Python3 environment using Anaconda Prompt ( pip install z3-solver ) and that's it.

The package appears in the [site-packages/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNupl.png) directory ( the package has _init__.py and all essential files including z3.py ). However, when I tried running [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kml8H.png) from Jupyter Notebook, it returns the following message: **NameError**: name 'Int' is not defined.

I've only used Anaconda for a short time so I'm not sure how installation works. It's really odd because the 'pip install' command works fine most of the times. Did I do something wrong or this package requires more configuration ?

Comment: Change Int to int

Comment: It doesn't work. Int is a class defined in z3 and the example I used is taken from their official Github repo so it's not realated to the syntax.

Comment: Do you have a file named `z3.py` in your project directory?

Comment: Did you follow the recommendations for using pip with Conda? See, for example: https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/.

Answer (score 4):

you have to write:

```
from z3 import *
```

which solved my `NameError: name 'Solver' is not defined` Exception

prerequisites:

```
pip install z3
pip install z3-solver
```

code example

```
from z3 import *
 
def main(): 
    
    s = Solver()
    x = Int('x')
    y = Int('y')
    s.add(x < 10)
```

Comment: Installing the "z3" package is a mistake.  "z3" is an old package for doing a compressed backup to or from AWS servers, unrelated to "z3-solver".

Answer (score 2):

You can run `conda install pip` and then run the `pip install z3-solver`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late update.

I've managed to solve the problem based on [this guide](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki/Using-Z3Py-on-Windows).

To permanently change the `sys.path` variable in `Anaconda,` I created a `.PTH file` which contains the path to `z3` and put it in *site-packages* directory.

You might need to copy the `libz3.dll` file to the right directory in order for it to work. 
Running `pip install z3-solver` does download the required files and put them in *site-packages* but I can't import `z3` from anywhere.

Maybe you also need to fix the path after using pip so Anaconda can recognize it. I did everything manually so I'm not sure why pip doesn't work in this case.

That's all I did to install `z3` on my `Windows`. Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

Lots of answers, but I had this problem and found:

- First, `pip install z3` installs an obsolete and unrelated [package](https://pypi.org/project/z3/) related to AWS backups.
- Second, `pip install z3-solver` installs only the interface to an installed installation of the z3 system, under the python library name `z3`.  It does not install the underlying z3 system and it does warn you that it does not exist.  If there is no underlying system, "import * from z3" will execute, but not import any useful functions.
- Third, the easiest way to install z3 is use your favorite package manager.  On macOS, I used `brew install z3`.

When the installation of both parts works, a good quick test is `from z3 import *; a,b = Reals('a b')`. If these statements execute, you are good.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in 2022.

**IMPORTANT:**
**Install using the following command**

```
pip install z3 z3-solver
```

I did not know about the z3-solver package so I installed it later but it didn't work. Same issue as you. Could import but the import only included half a dozen special dunder functions like `__file__` and others.

After all permutes of install, uninstall, add-to-$PATH ... later I just did this and it worked at once.